# hyperledger fabric make peer make: *** No rule to make target `peer'. Stop

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I try to build hyperledger fabric,I have installed the project as the guide devenv.md, but when I try to mak peer as the guide build.md ,it has the tips as above,
*vagrant@ubuntu-1404:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/devenv$ make peer
make: *** No rule to make target `peer'.  Stop.*

How to Solve This Problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: my computer is win7 64bit

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a Makefile on your folder? If I recall correclty the makefile is on `/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric` , not on the `/devenv/`.

You might still get an error from that folder (I recall) but you could try doing `make` first.

Edit:

Indeed, http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev-setup/build/ states just that:

```
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
make peer
```

Comment: yes ,the makefile is on the path ./hyperledger/fabric ,
when i try doing : make    at the 
/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric$,
it shows other error:  
Building golint
go get github.com/golang/lint/golint
package golang.org/x/tools/go/gcimporter15: unrecognized import path "golang.org/x/tools/go/gcimporter15" (https fetch: Get https://golang.org/x/tools/go/gcimporter15?go-get=1: dial tcp 216.58.221.145:443: i/o timeout)
Is this document   gcimporter15  necessary?

Comment: I solve the problem
I do the make peer  at the   ./hyperledger/fabric/build/bin 
then sucessful,
the document of hyperledger/fabric  maybe wrong or old